# Stop Jquery to automatic fire onclick event while rendering html table using innerHtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How to stop Jquery from firing onclick event while the html is rendering html table with buttons.
These buttons need to be present which inturns calls backend API for refresh reasons.
And refreshUser() need to be triggered manually when refresh button is clicked.

jqueryfile.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    refreshUser = function (userId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/services/svcCall/refreshUserDetails",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {format: 'json', userId: userId},
            success: function (response) {
                $('#userDetails-result').html("Refreshed completed.");
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#userDetails-result').html("<p>There was an error processing your request. Please try again.</p>");
            }
        });
    };
    $('#userDetails-search').click(function () {
        $('#userDetails-search').html("Fetching ...");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/services/svcCall/allUserDetails",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {format: 'json'},
            success: function (response) {
                var length = response.length;
                var outerString = '<br><br><table border = 2>';
                outerString += "<tr><td> UserDetails size present: " + length + "</td></tr>";
                var innerString = '<tr><td><table border = 1>';
                for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    innerString += "<tr>"
                        + "<td> JSON:" + JSON.stringify(response[i]) + "</td>"
                        + "<td> <input type=\"button\" onclick=\"" + refreshUser(response[i].userId) + "\" value=\" Refresh \"> </td></tr>";
                }
                innerString += "</table></td></tr>";
                outerString = outerString + innerString + "</table>";
                $('#userDetails-search').html(outerString);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#userDetails-search').html("<p>There was an error processing your request. Please try again.</p>");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

HTML file

```
<table>
    <tr><td><button id="userDetails-search">Find me all User Details</button></td></tr>

    <tr><td><section id="userDetails-search"> </section></td>
        <td><section id="userDetails-result"></section></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pass event parameter in click function and check value of `event.target` it will probably be unrefined , like `$('#userDetails-search').click(function (e) { if(e.target === undefined)return;` , I am using mobile device so can't test and answer, please debug the value of target, you can differentiate the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your onclick should put refreshUser in string instead

```
 onclick=\"refreshUser(" +response[i].userId + ")\"
```